# How to display star rating into my custom customer feedback grid view using renderer in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, review, ratings

This is my `listing.xml` code for rating . I want to display **star rating** to the custom feedback grid.

```
<column name="rating">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rating</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

I want Something like this 
[image: I want something like this.]

Comment: you can get the rating value from PDP page ..just use this logic

Comment: What is PDP page? Can you please explain it?Thank you

Comment: by default rating is available on PRODUCT DETAIL PAGE from there you can the value of ratings

Comment: Its a custom module and i am storing data into my custom table. On bases of the data stored in db, i want to display star rating as shown above.Currently its displaying 1 to 5 as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer. I create class for **rating.php** in **ui->component->Listing->column** and displayed value in **rating.html** file in **view->adminhtml->web->tamplate**. That worked for me. I will now return css class and add it to my html code to make it look bit better.Thank you all for you helping. If there is better way let me know.

**rating.php**

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if(isset($dataSource['data']['items'])){
        foreach($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item){
            if($item['rating']){
                $data = [];
                for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
                    if($i < $item['rating'])
                        $data[] = 'selected';
                    else
                        $data[] = 'notSelected';

                $item['rating'] = $data;
            }
        }
    }
    return parent::prepareDataSource($dataSource); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
```

**rating.html**

```
<div class="field required review-field-ratings">
<div class="control review-control-vote" >
    <!--  ko foreach: $col.getLabel($row())   -->
    <!-- ko if: $data == "selected"-->
    <span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">★</span>
    <!--/ko-->
    <!-- ko if: $data != "selected"-->
    <span style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">★</span>
    <!--/ko-->
    <!--    /ko    -->
</div>
```